# CentOS - Apache server not reflecting renewed certificate

Tags: apache, centos, ssl-certificate

The SSL Certificate for Apache server had expired yesterday. I renewed it with CA Cert, viewed the certificate, copied the contents into a .crt file which is referenced in ssl.conf. Restarted httpd server but still the browser throws "SEC_ERROR_EXPIRED_CERTIFICATE". What is even strange is that it shows the expired certificate. I changed the name of the .crt file and restarted httpd server and it failed to start saying the SSLCertificate was not found. That would mean it was referring to the .crt file I put after renewal from CA Cert.

Appreciate your help in resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue - I was referring to old certificate in another .conf file. So due to the conflict, it was fetching the old one itself. Once I removed that, it worked fine.